# on the vector product

Tags: linear-algebra

Can the product(element to element) of two vector $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ with the same dimension be written as the usual vector(or matrix) product?

Say $\vec{a}=[2,3],\vec{b}=[4,5]$ and $\vec{a}~\text{product(element to element)}~\vec{b}=[8,15]$

Thank you!

Comment: if you mean dot product ,then it is  just scalar  not vector,in your case a*b=23

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean I can add some other constant matrix like identity matrix, or other constant vector like $e_j$, anyway, I just want to get rid off that kind of unusual product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not if you mean standard matrix multiplication. The matrix product of two $n\times 1$ or $1\times n$ matrices does not exist. Even if you allow taking the transpose, the product of a $1\times n$ matrix and a $n\times 1$ matrix is $1\times 1$ while the product of a $n\times 1$ matrix and a $1\times n$ matrix is $n\times n$. None of these are vectors, so this can't be what you are looking for.

However, as Andreas pointed out, there *is* a name for the operation you are talking about, the Hadamard product, and it generalizes to all matrices.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I understand.

Answer (score 2):

For matrices there is the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) with
$    (A \circ B)_{i,j} = (A)_{i,j} \cdot (B)_{i,j}. $ So think of vectors as $1-\text{by}-2$ matrices.